# Contribute to Finance related projects

Tags: programming

I am currently a student and in the future would like to work as a software developer for a financial institution such as Bloomberg, Factset etc. I was looking to contribute  to some open source or develop a financial application that will not only build my profile but also help me learn. I am not sure where to start .I came across http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/about/ and was wondering if it can be used to develop applications not for commercial use but just for open source project. In addition i would love it if any senior or experienced developers is willing to mentor me i will work hard and dedicate myself but i really lack guidance.

Comment: Hi user2733436, welcome to quant.SE! Career advice is not on-topic here but I believe nsw's advice is valuable for you. Another idea is to get active on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're a student, the first place I would suggest you seek guidance would be from your professors. They could at least steer you in a direction of developing something that could be meaningful and appropriate for someone with your background (whatever that may be, your professors probably would know).

If you're looking for something open source, then I would suggest creating some useful R package. ;)